# ORACLE 11GPL/SQL cursor with dynamic when clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to use the following cursor in the PL/SQL procedure (running on Oracle 11g):

```
SELECT
        dateagregation as DATEAGREG,
        SUM(TRAITE3MOIS) as col1,
        SUM(TRAITE)      as col2
        FROM ttabdbordrescrit where dateagregation = P_AGREGATION_N
        AND directionid = P_DIRECTIONID
        AND celluleid = P_CELLULEID
        AND libelletabdbordrescritid IN (CASE
                        WHEN (YEAR(P_AGREGATION_N) >= 2020)
                        THEN
                          2, 26, 27
                        ELSE 
                           2
                     END)
```

but I have on SQLDEVELOPPER an ORA 00905 error with the line 2,26,27 in red!
(P_AGREGATION_N is a PL_SQL valid parameter)
What is wrong?

Is there another way to build a dynamic query?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: There is no `year()` function in Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `year` function unless you created one and you can't return a list like that from a `case` statement.  Assuming `p_agregation_n` is a `date` parameter, you want something like

```
AND (   (    p_agregation_n >= date '2020-01-01'
         and libelletabdbordrescritid in (2, 26, 27))
     or (    p_agregation_n <  date '2020-01-01' 
         and libelletabdbordrescritid = 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the parameter, but this:

```
WHEN (YEAR(P_AGREGATION_N) >= 2020)
```

There's no `YEAR` function in Oracle. If `P_AGREGATION_N` is a `DATE` (datatype), you could

```
when extract(year from p_agregation_n) >= 2020
```

If it is a string, use `SUBSTR` function.